# I run cifar10 on Tensorflow, but it show me some Error

Tags: python, tensorflow

everyone, I do a little change on `cifar10_train.py` and it occurs an error. 
the origin code in `cifar10_train.py` is:

```
from tensorflow.models.image.cifar10 import cifar10
```

and I change it to:

```
import cifar10.py
import cifar10_eval.py
import cifar10_input.py
```

The reason is that I want to change some codes in these three files, so I import these files by myself instead of importing from tensorflow. In this case, I do not change anything in these three files.

When I run the `cifar10_train.py`, The error is showed below:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-58-100:~$ python cifar10_train.py
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.7.5 locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cifar10_train.py", line 48, in <module>
    import cifar10
  File "/home/ubuntu/cifar10.py", line 43, in <module>
    """Number of images to process in a batch.""")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist packages/tensorflow/python/platform/flags.py", line 91, in DEFINE_integer
    _define_helper(flag_name, default_value, docstring, int)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/flags.py", line 65, in _define_helper
    type=flagtype)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1297, in add_argument
    return self._add_action(action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1671, in _add_action
    self._optionals._add_action(action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1498, in _add_action
    action = super(_ArgumentGroup, self)._add_action(action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1311, in _add_action
    self._check_conflict(action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1449, in _check_conflict
    conflict_handler(action, confl_optionals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1456, in _handle_conflict_error
    raise ArgumentError(action, message % conflict_string)
argparse.ArgumentError: argument --batch_size: conflicting option string(s): --batch_size
```

Any answer is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that both of these files declare the same command line argument, in which case you can fix it by removing the option from one of them.

Comment: Thank you, Allen! I find I duplicate some import command and correct it, also it still occurs new error, I will try to solve it.